# Can Hibernate Search be configured for NodeEntiny?

Tags: hibernate, neo4j, hibernate-search, spring-data-neo4

I am trying to build hibernate full text search for a `nodeEntity`. It  gives:

> Can't build query for type x.y.z.Object  which is neither configured
>   nor has any configured sub-types

My class is like below. I am using Neo4j database.

```
@NodeEntity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ClassName {

    @Index
    private String xyzId;

    @Index
    @Field(index = org.hibernate.search.annotations.Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
    private String xyz;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make any **Hibernate entity** managed by Hibernate Search you have to mark it with `org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed`.

So you're missing two things:

1. it must be an entity managed by Hibernate ORM (or OGM)
2. it's missing the `@Indexed` annotation on `ClassName`.

Your example looks like it's using a Neo4J native mapping; that won't work. You might want to look into [Hibernate OGM](http://hibernate.org/ogm/), which makes it possible to store actual Hibernate entities into NoSQL databases, including Neo4J.

Comment: I am using hibernate `OGM and used the indexed annotations that does not work gives  no entity found error unless I use entity property